# Python drawing images and dynamic shape size

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have a couple of questions. Firstly, I am wondering how to I get shape sizes for shapes I call to be dynamic, and adjust based on my movement of the window that they are in. Is there a simple command for this? Secondly, I am wondering if instead of using something like Turtle to draw images, how do I get an image to just appear once I run drawing code, as opposed to watching it be drawn?

```
from turtle import *
import math

radius = 100

t = turtle.Turtle()

radius = 100
colormode(255)
t.speed(1)
t.color(0,255,0)
fillcolor(200, 125, 200)  
t.begin_fill()
t.circle(radius)

t.end_fill()



exitonclick()
```

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: I added some code for clarity. While it runs, I don't want to watch it slowly draw a circle, I want to just appear when run from cmd. From here, once the image is drawn on a screen, I don't know how to get it to adjust based on the size of the display window that it is in, so the image is somehow tied to the display window size, and not hard coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can go about this is by designing a turtle cursor and stamping it.  Cursors are drawn all at once and have more graphics operations at their disposal, like resizing, shear, etc.  Here's a simple example using turtle's built in circle shape but you can just as easily design your own and register it as a cursor:

```
RADIUS = 100
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)

turtle = Turtle("circle", visible=False)
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()

turtle.pencolor(0, 255, 0)
turtle.fillcolor(200, 125, 200)
turtle.shapesize(RADIUS / CURSOR_SIZE, outline=5)

turtle.stamp()

turtle.goto(250, 250)
turtle.shapesize(2 * RADIUS / CURSOR_SIZE, outline=10)

turtle.stamp()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Awesome, that helped with the instant render of the circle(s), thanks a heap.